# Detrending Non-Stationary Time Series with MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have the data similar to the following below that I need to make stationary in order to then fit DecisionTreeRegressor. I read that decision trees work better with stationary time series. This data has an obvious trend, but no real seasonality.

[image]

I only have 4 years of data for each school. Is this enough data to determine and detrend? I tried to apply a log transformation to detrend so far, but it still appears to be trending downward. I also tried seasonal_decompose from statsmodels, but I wasn't sure how to apply it with multi-indexed data like this.

How do I detrend this time series to make it stationary?

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

years = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
schools = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

schools_rows = [x for b in years for x in schools]
years_rows = [x for b in schools for x in years]
budget_rows = [100, 80, 75, 30, 200, 175, 100, 90, 100, 50, 45, 40, 250, 200, 100, 50, 
               200, 90, 75, 100]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Year": years_rows, "School":schools_rows, "Budget": budget_rows})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html)
to check if the time series is stationary.

You can differentiate the series for each school using:

```
diff_df = df.pivot(index='Year', columns='School', values='Budget').diff().dropna()
print(diff_df)

School      A      B      C      D      E
Year                                     
2017     75.0 -120.0 -160.0  100.0 -150.0
2018   -130.0   20.0  -15.0 -125.0   50.0
2019      5.0  -60.0   15.0  -45.0    0.0
```

You could also try to use some `Box-Cox` transformation to reduce the heteroesticity:

```
diff_lp_df = (df.assign(Budget=np.log1p(df['Budget']))
                .pivot(index='Year',
                       columns='School', 
                       values='Budget').diff().dropna())
print(diff_lp_df)

School         A         B         C         D         E
Year                                                    
2017    0.555363 -0.908856 -1.014593  0.688184 -1.371479
2018   -1.341843  0.220671 -0.180126 -0.972572  0.683295
2019    0.103184 -0.901548  0.180126 -0.896746  0.000000
```